# Ghost files on NTFS Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

AllDup keeps finding files that don't exist in Windows Explorer:

[image: AllDup list]

The file in Ivor/Ivor does exist, but the file in Ivor/ does not, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steinberg\VSTPlugins\Ivor>dir /a
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 109C-A77D

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Steinberg\VSTPlugins\Ivor

2016-02-07  04:06 PM    <DIR>          .
2016-02-07  04:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
2012-05-10  07:30 PM    <DIR>          Ivor
2014-04-27  07:47 AM         2,193,416 Ivor - Manual.pdf
2014-04-27  06:53 AM         6,790,656 Ivor.dll
               2 File(s)      8,984,072 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   6,493,270,016 bytes free
```

If I get file properties within AllDup, it gives an icon with a lock on it:

[image: File Properties]

I don't understand how these files can both exist and not exist, and I've never seen this with AllDup before.

If I try to open the file, nothing happens.

If I have it delete them to the Recycle Bin and then restore them, they appear where it says they were.  I'm confused.

(The original zip files that created these folders are here http://xen-arts.net/vsti/)

Comment: If you look at your screenshot, you see that the attribute for the files you can't find are AI. If I'm not mistaken the I is for not indexed.

Comment: list:  read-only (R), hidden (H), system (S), directory (D), archive (A), encrypted (E), normal (N), temporary (T), sparse file (P), reparse point as with symbolic link or junction (L), compressed (C), offline (O), not content indexed (I)

Comment: @LPChip Yeah I saw that but it just means that Windows Search won't find it by content, only by file name?  http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/222954-file-attributes.html

Comment: I can't reproduce this; the file really isn't there for me, not in the ZIP, not on the file system. Can you see them if you boot from a different OS?